# Start two threads in the same time but avoid using join after, this is for android program

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

i have  two threads starting at the same time in my android program for downloading some packets.

```
ServerIP = WifiServer;
Thread thread22 = new Thread (new CallDownloader(fileToReceive, ServerIP, WifiServer, MobileServer));
thread22.start();
ServerIP = MobileServer;
Thread thread23 = new Thread (new CallDownloader(fileToReceive, ServerIP, WifiServer, MobileServer));
thread23.start();
```

i want to download some files from two servers at the same time. 
if i use under every thread the thread.joim();

```
 ServerIP = WifiServer;
        Thread thread22 = new Thread (new CallDownloader(fileToReceive, ServerIP, WifiServer, MobileServer));
        thread22.start();
    thread22.join();
 ServerIP = MobileServer;
        Thread thread23 = new Thread (new CallDownloader(fileToReceive, ServerIP, WifiServer, MobileServer));
        thread23.start();
         thread23.join();
```

the code is not parallel but serialized. and i don't want this. I know that join is waiting to finish the first and after continue to the other.

when i take out the thread.join(); its downloading whatever it wants and not what i want to download. and is using only the first thread and it isn't going to the second.

how i can avoid the join?
because i need thread to call the connection.
if you need more details tell me to put.

here is the main code.

```
Queue<String> fileparts = new LinkedList<String>();

    Time = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
    long Time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    StartTime = Time2;


    int intnumbOfChunks = Integer.parseInt(numbOfChunks);
    intnumbOfChunks = 250;

    for (int i = 0; i < intnumbOfChunks; i++) {

        fileToClaim = "";
        fileToClaim = "bigbang.mp4";
        fileToClaim = String.format("%s.part%06d", fileToClaim, i);

        fileparts.add(fileToClaim);

    }

 int i=0;



 while (!fileparts.isEmpty()) {
fileToReceive = fileparts.peek();

ServerIP = WifiServer;
                Thread thread22 = new Thread (new CallDownloader(fileToReceive, ServerIP, WifiServer, MobileServer));
                thread22.start();
                thread22.start();
                try {
                    thread22.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ServerIP = MobileServer;
                Thread thread23 = new Thread (new CallDownloader(fileToReceive, ServerIP, WifiServer, MobileServer));
                thread23.start();
                try {
                    thread22.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Join(fileToReceive));
                thread3.start();            
                try {
                    thread3.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                fileparts.remove();}
```

the downloader thread is

```
public class Downloader {

    final String fileToReceive;

    boolean fileDownloaded = false;
    Socket clientSocket;

    public Downloader(String fileToReceive) {

        this.fileToReceive = fileToReceive;


    }

    public void download(String ServerIP) {
        //Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("kanw connect me ti porta 3248");
            clientSocket = new Socket(ServerIP, 3248);
            System.out.println("egine i sundesi me ti porta 3248");
            System.out.println("stelnw to " + fileToReceive);

            BufferedWriter BuffWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            BuffWriter.write(fileToReceive + "\n");
            BuffWriter.flush();
            System.out.println("esteila to " + fileToReceive);
            InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            System.out.println("dimiourgo to fakelo vid ");
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/vid/");
            // File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());
            dir.mkdirs();
            System.out.println("arxizw tin lipsei tou chunk");
            byte[] longBytes = new byte[8];
            readFully(clientSocket, longBytes);
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(longBytes);
            long fileLength = bb.getLong();
            System.out.println("apothikeusi arxeiou");
            // save
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir,
                    fileToReceive));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            int readBytes = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                readBytes += len1;

            }

            if (readBytes == fileLength) {
                this.fileDownloaded = true;
            }
            System.out.println("Receiving the file " + fileToReceive);

            System.out.println("File Recieved");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Client stopped");
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                if (clientSocket != null && !clientSocket.isClosed()) {
                    clientSocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void readFully(Socket clientSocket, byte[] buffer)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("readfully");
        InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        int remaining = buffer.length;
        int read = 0;
        while (remaining > 0) {

            read = inputStream.read(buffer, buffer.length - remaining,  remaining);

            if (read < 0) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            remaining -= read;
        }
        System.out.println("exit");
    }


    public boolean IsDownloaded() {

        return this.fileDownloaded;
    }


}
```

CallDownloader class is the thread

```
public void run() {


        System.out.println("connecting tou "+ServerIP);
        Downloader d = new Downloader(fileToReceive);
        //Downloader1 d1 = new Downloader1(fileToReceive);
        d.download(ServerIP);
}
```

Comment: `"its downloading whatever it wants and not what i want to download"` what does it mean exactly?

Comment: What happens if you start both threads and then `join()` the two threads, one after the other?

Comment: i have a list that have inside some chunk names. i am doing a while as is not empty to ask with the threads the chunks. so reuest the chunk to Client bigbang.mp4.part000026 Sending the chunk to Client bigbang.mp4.part000027 Sending the chunk to Client bigbang.mp4.part000028 and after that it says downloaded downloaded downloaded. and i don't want this. but i want. Sending the chunk to Client bigbang.mp4.part000026 downloaded Sending the chunk to Client bigbang.mp4.part000027 downloaded.//////// Ted Hopp it is not using the second thread. I don't know why is doing that

Comment: It is still not clear what you are trying to do.  My guess is that your problem is not with `join`, but with the data synchronization between threads, which you do not discuss at all.

Comment: i have put more information under

Comment: What do you mean that "it is not using the second thread"? Does the second thread not run? It doesn't wait to `join()`? Something else? Also, why are you using `join()` in the first place? If this is being run on the UI thread, you should be using a call-back from the thread. Take a look at using `AsyncTask` as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: and how i can download from both servers the same time?